# Accept actual changes to update in database C#, MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

The situation is : I have a few dedicated clients (terminals) and one database, the operations perform in the following order :

1. First client take actual row from database
2. Second client take actual row from database
3. First client make some changes and update database row
4. Second client try to update the same row but this version is older than firstclient - there is a collision.

How to resolve it better ? Is there is some solution in MS SQL server ?

Comment: Essentially, you are asking about a tutorial on ADO.NET concurrency. Have you tried to find one? MSDN has entire sections about it with many articles [like this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about it. Things are a bit different when you use ORMs like Entity Framework or NHibernate, but you don't mention what you actually use.

Comment: Thanks for advice ! I'll read, i'm interested in the ado.net approach.

Answer (score 1):

Optimistic concurrency is used to detect this collision, which sounds like you are able to detect it already.

Usually you take one of two approaches, last in wins where you always overwrite changes, or first in wins where the second write will fail.

If you fail the second write, then you usually display a message to the user that data has changed and their changes will be lost, then you refresh the data.

Another option is to show them their current edits and then also show them the data after refreshing it(the first saved edits), and letting them choose whether they want to overwrite the changes.

This process is called conflict resolution, and the approach you take depends on who your users are and the business rules regarding the data in question.